# Ef Core 2.0 - Adding entities after deleting server side data causes exceptions and duplicate data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I found an interesting problem with EF core changetracking and how it's adding unwanted duplicate data to my database.

Order of operations:

1. Add new "Order" entity
2. Delete order using a manual query on the database
3. Add another new "Order" entity
4. An exception is thrown: `The instance of entity type 'Order' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'OrderId'} is already being tracked.` (The new entity still gets added to the ChangeTracker)
5. Add another new "Order" entity
6. It worked this time, but it inserted two new Orders and now there is duplicate data.

I'm not using this in a web application, it's a service that maintains a single connection context because it's constantly processing a queue of data. But I must accept that data can be deleted outside of this context/service.

Example:

```
public async Task TestException()
{
    var dirtyOrders = _allOrders.Where(x => x.IsDirty).ToList();

    foreach(var order in dirtyOrders)
    {
        await CreateAsync(order);
        order.IsDirty=false;
    }

    Sql("TRUNCATE dbo.Orders;");

    dirtyOrders = _allOrders.Where(x => x.IsDirty).ToList();

    foreach(var order in dirtyOrders)
    {
        await CreateAsync(order); // exception thrown
        order.IsDirty=false;
    }

}

public async Task<Order> CreateAsync(Order order)
{
    _dbContext.OrderBook.Add(order);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return order;
}
```

Comment: when are you calling `SaveChanges`? Also Order has auto increment or you are adding primary key manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate method to delete your model to avoid the EF's model lifecycle and tracking. hope it'll work.

```
private bool DeleteModel(Order order)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"DELETE Order WHERE Id={order.Id}");
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}


public bool SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    try
    {
        //Delete Model First
        if(DeleteModel(order))
        {
            _context.Orders.Add(order);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No this won’t work. The model doesn’t exist yet, it’s upon create this happens. There is nothing to pre-delete because it’s a model without a primary key at this point.

Comment: @MichaelBrown i added order.Id you can use any other column(property).

Comment: please edit your question and add some codes as you tried.

Comment: I've updated with a crude code sample, and I found the cause of the error as being using Truncate vs delete which is resetting the auto-increment to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the problem was. Because I was using Truncate to wipe the data it was resetting the auto-increment sequence to 1. Order #1 was already in the ChangeTracker after truncate and when it went to insert another order, the db returned a primary key of '1' which already was present in the ChangeTracker. Subsequent calls may refresh the changetracker, but your entity still sits in there in the state "Added" despite the exception, and a future call to Add that same record and call SaveChanges will now insert two duplicate records.

While I can avoid this condition by not resetting sequences, there isn't an easy way to prevent EF from running into this condition. I would think the behavior should be to overwrite the entry in Changetracker when in the "Added" state, not to throw an exception. The exception does not contain the key that was in conflict because it came from the server so there's no good way to programatically deal with it.

At the very least, I can remove it from changeTracking if SaveChangesAsync() fails to prevent duplicate rows from showing up in the future.

```
public async Task<Order> CreateAsync(Order order)
{
    _dbContext.OrderBook.Add(order);
    try
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch(DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        _dbContext.OrderBook.Remove(order);
        throw ex;
    }
    return order;
}
```